# Can't write an svg inside button in react app

Tags: reactjs, svg

This is the code that I am getting the error on. I don't think there is anything wrong with the code I wrote

```
import { ReactComponent as LogoutIconSvg } from "../../assets/svg/logout-user.svg";

<button type="button" className={styles.profilemenu__item} style={{ "--icon": "#F94687 " }} onClick={logout}>
    <LogoutIconSvg />
    Logout
  </button>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>.
```

Comment: Hey, Ghayas! can you confirm these things in your code? First, check that your button is not enclosed in another `button` tag. Second, are you using `vite` in your react project? If yes, then **Vite** doesn't handle SVG import out of the box, so then try **0xtaofeek** solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot render an Svg as a component. To do that, you need to create a component that returns that svg, such as:

```
//LogoutIconSvg.js 
const LogoutIconSvg =()=>
  {
      return (
       <svg>
       ...
       </svg>
       );
   }


 export default LogoutIconSvg
```

Then, you can import and use as:

```
import  LogoutIconSvg from "..path/LogoutIconSvg";

<button type="button" className={styles.profilemenu__item} style={{ "--icon": "#F94687 " }} onClick={logout}>
    <LogoutIconSvg />
    Logout
  </button>
```

or,
use the import svg as an image not as a component:

```
<img src={LogoutIconSvg} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly render svg as a component. You need to render it using `img` tag.

And also you're not importing your svg correctly because svg is a static file, not a component.

Try importing it like below

```
import LogoutIconSvg from "../../assets/svg/logout-user.svg";

<img src={LogoutIconSvg} />
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. Getting the same error and also cant render the svg either

Comment: I've edited my solution. Please try it.